# Understanding gjs memory managment warning

Tags: gtk, gjs

I'm new to `gjs` and `gtk`, so this may be very basic, but I did not find any other question regarding this.

While trying to understand the gjs bindings of gtk and gdk, I wanted to write a small script that would log the dimensions of the monitor where a window would open, so I came up with the following one:

```js
import Gtk from 'gi://Gtk?version=4.0'
import Gdk from 'gi://Gdk?version=4.0'

// Gtk needs to be initialized to get a non-null default display, I think
Gtk.init()

const {Display, Surface} = Gdk
const display = Display.get_default()
const surface = Surface.new_toplevel(display)

const {geometry: {width, height}} = display.get_monitor_at_surface(surface)
console.log(`Width:  ${width}`)
console.log(`Height: ${height}`)
surface.destroy()
```

While this script exits successfully (status code 0), it logs something like the following line:

```
(gjs:12345): Gjs-CRITICAL **: 00:00:00.000: Object 0x112233445566 of type GdkWaylandToplevel has been finalized while it was still owned by gjs, this is due to invalid memory management.
```

However, the following experiments left me confused as to how to appropriately modify this script:

- Removing the `surface.destroy()` line logs a warning saying `losing last reference to undestroyed surface` which seems fair since that surface was not destroyed.
- Appending a line with `console.log('appended')` logs that message, so destroying the surface did not throw any error (I tested this before ensuring that the status code of the original script was 0); however, I don't know if something else may trigger an error (like running the GLib main loop).

What would be the appropriate way to manage the memory in this script?

Edit:

While integrating the aquired dimensions to run a nested wayland session with the appropriate size, I realized that the critical message is logged when the script finished on its own but not when it is aborted via Ctrl+C. A minimal working example that does not log any irrelevant messages is:

```js
import Gtk from 'gi://Gtk?version=4.0'
import Gdk from 'gi://Gdk?version=4.0'
import Gio from 'gi://Gio'

Gtk.init()

const {Display, Surface} = Gdk
const {Subprocess, SubprocessFlags: {SEARCH_PATH_FROM_ENVP}} = Gio

Gio._promisify(Subprocess.prototype, 'wait_async', 'wait_finish')

const display = Display.get_default()
const surface = Surface.new_toplevel(display)
const {geometry: {width, height}} = display.get_monitor_at_surface(surface)
surface.destroy()

await Subprocess.new(
  ['sleep', '5'],
  SEARCH_PATH_FROM_ENVP
).wait_async(null)
```

As explained a bit earlier, if we wait 5 secends after running this script, the script finishes on its own and logs the critical message; however, if we press Ctrl+C before that, it aborts and that message is never logged.

Comment: It's possible running a main loop would resolve this issue, but otherwise the memory issue is likely in GTK or GJS. It's hard to say without a lot more testing and investigation for certain, though.

Comment: @andy.holmes Thank you for your comment; I run a couple of experiments and edited my question with a minimal working example of them. I manage to spawn subprocesses, wich is what I wanted to do anyway, but it bothers me not understanding that critical log.

By the way, this is a bit unrelated, but do you know how to express that subprocess object using the standard js instantiation `new Subprocess(...)`? I managed to do that for `SubprocessLauncher`, but not for `Subprocess`.

Comment: Not sure I can really help with the error, maybe try `null`-ing the variables before the script exits so they can be collected.

`Gio.Subprocess` implements `Gio.Initiable`, so you'll have to call `init(Gio.Cancellable|null)` on the object before it can be used. The `Gio.Subprocess.new()` constructor function does this for you.

Comment: @andy.holmes Thank you, I didn't know that I had to call `.init(Gio.Cancellable|null)` after instantiation for objects that implement `Gio.Initiable`. Changing that did nothing for the `Gjs-Critical` log, though (as expected, since that log is about the Gdk.Surface).

Comment: I just managed to get rid of that log by calling either `surface.ref()` or `surface.ref_sink()` before destroying (Inspired by your previous comment, I decided to pay more attention to the inherited methods). Should I post this as a solution? I still don't understand what is happening, so if you could explain it in an answer, I'd rather accept that instead of just explaining how to get rid of that bothersome log by myself without really understanding the issue.

(Sorry for the consecutive comment, it did not fit as an edition to the previous comment)

Comment: I couldn't say, you should probably open an issue at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/issues

Comment: @andy.holmes I was a bit busy, but I just opened that issue (issue 592). For the time being, I'll be posting what I did as an answer to give closure to this question and update it depending on the feedback I get there. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### This workaround relies on a bug that is already patched and will be released in GNOME 46; please, read the update.

Executing `surface.ref()` before destroying the surface got rid of the message.

```js
import Gtk from 'gi://Gtk?version=4.0'
import Gdk from 'gi://Gdk'

// Gtk needs to be initialized to get a non-null default display, I think
Gtk.init()

const {Display, Surface} = Gdk
const display = Display.get_default()
const surface = Surface.new_toplevel(display)

const {geometry: {width, height}} = display.get_monitor_at_surface(surface)
console.log(`Width:  ${width}`)
console.log(`Height: ${height}`)
surface.ref()
surface.destroy()
```

I still don't understand why, but as a suggestion from @andy.holmes, I opened an issue on the `gjs` project. I'll update this answer with the relevant feedback I get there.

### Updates:

The general rule of thumb is not to `destroy` objects unless there is a reason to do so documented in the [official documentation](https://gjs-docs.gnome.org/) since reference counting should take care of releasing resources in most cases. Moreover, if for some reason, the `destroy` method is used or expected to be used somewhere, all holders of this reference should listen for its `destroy` signal and release such reference, which is an unneeded complication most of the time, as explained by @andy.holmes [here](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/when-to-destroy-in-gjs/18861).

The behaviour described earlier was due to a bug addressed in [issue 592 of gjs](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/-/issues/592), where an unnecessary warning was issued if the `Gdk.Surface` lost all references without been destroyed. Further information regarding the bug can be found there.